# browser does not render fadeIn and fadeOut until animation is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've some basic code to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` texts continuously:

```
function animateDonors(timeBetweenAnimation) {

    var donors = $('.donor div.comm');

    var donorsLength = donors.length;

    if(donorsLength < 2)
        return false;

    var donorsIndex = -1;

    function showNextDonor() {
        ++donorsIndex;
        donors.eq(donorsIndex % donorsLength)
            .fadeIn(1500)
            .delay(timeBetweenAnimation)
            .fadeOut(1500, showNextDonor);
    }

    showNextDonor();
}
```

For some reason, when I view the result in the browser, I can't see the fades but I can see the text changes.

So for example if I have 2 fading texts I will see Text1 and then Text2 with no transition at-all.

When I viewed the elements in Chrome with dev-tools, it seems like the `opacity` property is indeed being changed but the browser simply doesn't show it. Why is that?

Comment: Why are you doing `donors.eq(donorsIndex % donorsLength)` instead of just `donors.eq(donorsIndex)` ?

Comment: @Derek to preserve the loop. if I don't when it goes over 2 in this example, there would be no matched element

Comment: Nothing wrong with this script. Can you please show the HTML? Could you reproduce the problem in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/zceKN/413/ or use the Stack Snippets. Did you try other browsers or computers?

Comment: @kfirba gotcha. I saw the `%` symbol as a `/` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seems like I had transition bound to the element that I was trying to fade and it somehow interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If the below jsfiddle gives you the same problem, then the issue is you don't have enough RAM/GPU.

http://jsfiddle.net/zceKN/412/

This does a simple:

```
$('#foo').fadeIn(1500).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems I forgot to mention that the code works outside my project. It's unlikely that I don't have enough RAM/GPU or even CPU since I'm developing on a 8cores 3.8GHz CPU 8GB RAM and OC GTX 570. Any other idea?

Comment: @kfirba can you post the actual HTML structure of the donors?

Comment: I was just about to. While doing so, I figured out what the problem was. It seems like i had a transition bound to the element so it somehow interrupted with the jQuery animation.